# looping through variable names according to their prefix

Tags: loops, local-variables, stata

I have to carry out a number of paired t-tests, and I was wondering how to automate the overall procedure.
Suppose I have only the following variables:

```
int_ma    est_ma    tot_ma    int_pa    est_pa    tot_pa
```

What I need is to compute:

```
ttest int_ma=int_pa
ttest est_ma=est_pa
ttest tot_ma=tot_pa
```

Of course in some way it should be possible to exploit the fact that each pair has a unique prefix and the "_pa, _ma" suffixes, but unfortunately I cannot find an easy way to refer to only a part of each variable name..

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. I would use a `foreach` loop with a general list. Here I loop over your three prefixes, which Stata passes to the loop as local macros, and append `_ma` and `_pa` to `generate` and `ttest` the variables.

```
* generate some data
clear
set obs 100 
foreach x in int est tot {
    foreach y in ma pa {
        generate `x'_`y' = runiform()
    }
}

* -ttest- in -foreach- loop
foreach x in int est tot {
    ttest `x'_pa = `x'_ma
}
```

The `foreach` help file is a worth a few reads, as is the `macro` help file. The syntax is a little odd at first (more like bash scripting than R or Matlab), but it is very flexible.

Comment: A tutorial on `foreach` is accessible in _Stata Journal_ 2(2): 202-222 (2002). Typing `search foreach` in Stata leads to a clickable link to a .pdf version. (Note also that the tag "local-variables" here is a solecism in Stata, but I don't have enough reputation to introduce a more appropriate new tag "local-macros".)

Comment: I often use the  `foreach x of var ` notation.  `unab` might also be helpful.